# Intel TSX: xbegin always returns 0

Tags: intel, intel-tsx

I am writing some programs which contains RTM transactional regions. I have checked my machine supports HLE and RTM using `cpuid` instruction. However, I notice that the `xbegin` instruction always returns zero (the value in rax register), which indicates that the transaction is aborted. So I write a quite simple demo using `xbegin` and `xend` instruction, and do not insert any instructions between them.

The code described above is:

```cpp
int main() {
    asm volatile(".byte 0xc7, 0xf8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00" ::"r"(-1ul)); // xbegin machine code
    asm volatile(".byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xd5"); // xend machine code
    return 0;
}
```

The corresponding assembly code is:

```
00000000000005fa <main>:
 5fa:   48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
 601:   c7 f8 03 00 00 00       xbeginq 60a <main+0x10>
 607:   0f 01 d5                xend   
 60a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 60f:   c3                      retq
```

In this code, I set the fallback address in `xbegin` with the address of the next instruction of `xend`. So whether the transaction aborts or not, the code can finish execution normally. Then I use `perf` to profile the execution of this code, and I find that this transaction aborts due to HLE-unfriendly instructions. I don't know the reason.

```
$ sudo perf stat -e rtm_retired.start ./demo     
                                                                                                                                               
 Performance counter stats for './demo':
                              
                 1      rtm_retired.start

       0.000614539 seconds time elapsed                                               
                                                                                                 
       0.000634000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys 

$ sudo perf stat -e rtm_retired.commit ./demo                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                             
 Performance counter stats for './demo':                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                             
                 0      rtm_retired.commit                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                             
       0.000657118 seconds time elapsed                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                             
       0.000616000 seconds user         
       0.000000000 seconds sys

$ sudo perf stat -e rtm_retired.aborted_unfriendly ./demo

 Performance counter stats for './demo':

                 1      rtm_retired.aborted_unfriendly                                   

       0.000617362 seconds time elapsed

       0.000609000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

My machine configuration:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
microcode: 0xf0
OS: Linux 5.4.0-150-generic, Ubuntu 18.04.1
```

**Update**:
I have noticed an [article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059422/processors.html), which means that Intel has disabled TSX through a microcode update. They added an new CPUID bit to indicate this change. I have checked this bit and found that it is set on my processor. So the RTM regions cannot be executed successfully.

Comment: Have you checked if your kernel enables RTM?  In my 6.4.9 (Arch Linux) kernel on i7-6700k, `dmesg` includes `[    0.135426] TAA: Mitigation: TSX disabled`.  This disables both RTM and HLE.  (HLE is permanently disabled by microcode updates; RTM can be enabled but my kernel apparently ignores the `tsx=on` kernel command line option that is supposed to re-enable RTM; https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html)  The `0xf0` microcode that both our Skylake CPUs are running definitely disables HLE.  (My `/proc/cpuinfo` doesn't include hle or rtm, nor does `lscpu`.)

Comment: `xbeginq 60a` will end up executing the `mov $0, %eax` whether or not the transaction aborts.  It's only your `perf` output that tells us anything.  (You could count all three counters in one execution with `perf stat -e rtm_retired.start,rtm_retired.commit,rtm_retired.aborted_unfriendly ./a.out`.  Set `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` to 0 or maybe 1 so you don't need `sudo` for normal use of `perf`.)

Comment: Also, `"r"(-1ul)` doesn't ask for the result in RAX; use `"a"` if you want GCC to pick that register.  And as your `objdump` output shows, your binutils supports `xbegin`, no need to obfuscate by manually encoding it with `.byte`

Comment: Thank you for your patient answers. I have checked whether my processor and kernel supports Intel TSX using `cpuid` instruction, and the results are `CPUID.07H.EBX.HLE [bit 4] = 1` and `CPUID.07H.EBX.RTM [bit 11] = 1`, which indicate that my processor supports TSX according to Intel manual. `dmesg` contains `[    0.103870] TAA: Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers [    0.110846] TAA CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html for more details.`, so I think my kernel enables RTM.

Comment: I rerun the perf with only one command contains all three events, but get the same result: the RTM execution starts but not commits.

Comment: Good find with that Intel article; I guess I was mistaken that it was possible for the kernel to re-enable RTM on CPUs affected by the microcode update, only to fully disable it in CPUID so it doesn't even advertize the now-useless always-aborting xbegin.  But also it seems to be saying that more recent generations of Skylake-based microarchitectures do still have working TSX, and so do Ice Lake and later I guess.  You should post that as an *answer* to your own question, not an edit to the question.

Comment: Correction: Ice Lake removed the feature.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions#History_and_bugs  Sapphire Rapids has a TSXLDTRK extension apparently.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed an [article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059422/processors.html), which means that Intel has disabled TSX through a microcode update. They added an new CPUID bit to indicate this change. I have checked this bit and found that it is set on my processor. So the RTM regions cannot be executed successfully.